# create installer to make google chrome shortcut of a site

Tags: google-chrome, windows-installer, installation

is there a way to create installer to make google chrome shortcut of a site?

I made a web app and instead of trying to get multiple computers to type the url, I created a shortcut of chrome with this command.

```
--app=example.com/blah/blah
```

Is there a way that i can create an shortcut with the command and compile it, with an icon?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to point to Chrome if that is already the default web browser from the machine. All you need to create is an URL shortcut. All MSI authoring tools should be able to do that.

With the free edition of Advanced Installer you can do like this:

- if you don't have AI, [download and install it](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html)
- launch the application and create a "Simple" project, like in the first step from [this tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html)
- then just create a shortcut to URL in the Files and Folders page, using the option "New Shortcut To -> URL... " and set the URL desired in the configuration dialog of the new shortcut.
- save and build the project, the MSI will be generated and you can now install it on the desired machines

Download this [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5392761/SharedOnPublicForums/URL_Shortcut_Demo.aip) file to see how it looks if you have problems following the steps above.